# How to get JS to execute for whole class?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, playback-rate

I have many videos on my page and I've created and extra button on the video to speed up video, and it is working if I call getElementById.
Is it possible to use one Javascript for all videos on the page?  Since it's around 80+, then would be lots of duplicated javascript code, as I also have to make button to go back to speed 1x

HTML page block looks like this.

```
....
<div class="LigthBox">
        <a href="#DVDList" class="close" id="clVid1"></a> <a href="javascript:Play15();" class="speed15"> <a href="javascript:Play1();" class="speed1"></a> 
        <video class="Video_LitBox" id="DVD101" controls preload="none" poster="img/DVDThb-101.png"> <source src="res/vid-str.php?play_video=101" type="video/mp4"> </video>  
        <h3 class="DVid_title">101 Intro </h3>
        <p class="DVid_body">101 Intro description .....</p>
    </div>
....
```

and below in script area I have the following:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  var vid = document.getElementById("DVD101");
  vid.onended = function() { 
    alert("The video has ended");
    fireEvent( document.getElementById('clVid1'), 'click'); 
  } 

  function Play1() { 
    vid.playbackRate = 1;
  }
  function Play15() { 
    vid.playbackRate = 1.5;
  }
</script>
```

so variable vid to be somehow defined for every video on the page or any other work around if any. btw fireevent also doesn't work after video finishes, alert shows but doesn't close the the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in solution.  Thanks to @Aaron_Actu suggestion and some digging I ended up making just one short JS with argument (video-speed)

so call from html looks the same for all videos

```
....
<a href="javascript:PlaySpeed(15);" class="speed15"></a>
....
```

and at the bottom of the page script looks like

```
....
  function PlaySpeed(vspd) { 
    var vid = document.querySelectorAll('video');
    for (var i=0; i<vid.length; i++) {     
      vid[i].playbackRate = vspd / 10;
    }
  }
...
```

I pass "video-speed" with 10x multiplier so that argument is an integer

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe change the selector, instead of using `getElementById()` method you should try :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('video')
```

which will return an array with all video instances. Then, you can easily do whatever you want with a simple [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...in) or [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach) loop.

[More details](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) about `querySelectorAll()` method.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron_Actu So are you suggesting to get querySelectorAll at the start of the JS and then within function I use loop to run through all id of the videos, and (and each video should have own ID in HTML code)?

Comment: Actually, `document.querySelectorAll('video')` will select every video element, so no need to use ID anymore.

Comment: but when I tried without for loop it didn't work

Comment: You should really take a look at [1] and [2]. [1] Doc of querySelectorAll. [2] Good pratices when posting and exchanging in a forum. For eg, instead of saying it does not works, tells us what error you get :)